# Should I use INT64_C as "int64_t literal" ...?

Tags: c++, literals, int64

How can I write portable code to compare a constant integer value with an int64_t variable across different platforms (MacOS and Ubuntu)?

```cpp
int64_t a = 2;
std::min(1, a);
```

- Fails to compile on MacOS when I use `1L` as the constant value.
- Using `1LL` also fails to compile on Ubuntu 20.04.

I found INT64_C as a potential solution, but the documentation is unclear.

Comment: It "fails to compile"? How? What errors do you get from your compiler?

Comment: "no matching function for call to 'min'", since int64_t is `long long` under mac and `long` under ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int64_t a = 2;
std::min(1, a); // error (unless int64_t is int)
```

Replacing `1` by `INT64_C(1)` is likely to "work", but it's not guaranteed. The `INT64_C` macro expands to an expression of type `int_least64_t`. That's likely to be the same type as `int64_t`, but it's not guaranteed. For example, if `long` and `long long` are both 64 bits, it's possible that `int_least64_t` could be `long` and `int64_t` could be `long long`. There's not much reason for an implementation to define them differently, but you shouldn't rely on that.

It's defined that way because, in most contexts, a constant of type `int_least64_t` is usable in a context where you need an `int64_t` value, since it will likely be promoted. Arguments to `std::min` are an exception; you need an expression that's actually of type `int64_t`.

There is no syntax for defining a literal of type `int64_t`. But you can have a constant expression of that type by using a conversion:

```
int64_t a = 2;
std::min(int64_t(1), a);
```

Or you can define a constant of the right type and use that instead of the literal:

```
std::int64_t a = 2;
constexpr int64_t one = 1;
std::min(one, a);
```

Answer (score 4):

The first answer provided quite exotic solutions. What you need is just setting the parameters type:

```
int64_t a = 2;
std::min<int64_t>(1, a);
```